# Correct way to define and use StateT along different "return type" functions

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

Let `State'` be my program state with some data.

```
type State' m a = StateT Int m a
```

I would use it in some computations.

Examples:

```
-- genData, return some string (using Int value and State')
genData :: Int -> State' String
genData n = ...

-- genDatas, return multiple strings
genDatas :: Int -> State' [String]
genDatas n = mapM genData [1..n]

-- printLog, write log message (enumerating lines)
printLog :: String -> State' IO ()
printLog msg = do
  n <- get
  let n' = n + 1
  put n'
  liftIO $ putStrLn $ "Message #" ++ (show n') ++ ": " ++ msg
```

I think is not the correct way do it:

```
-- If I need a "in context function" returning a Int value...
--
-- addExtra, return current Int in state plus x
addExtra :: Int -> State' Identity Int
addExtra x = get >>= return.(+x)
```

To use my `addExtra` function in some monad context I do it:

```
doComplex :: State' IO ()
doComplex = do
  printLog "Starting process..."

  -- It's ugly!
  s <- get
  Identity (w, s') <- return $ runStateT (addExtra 5) s
  put s' -- save state

  printLog $ "computed value: " ++ (show w)
```

What is the correct way to share my `State'` monad along different functions? (as `IO a` is doing)

Thank you!

(I have read some tutorials and some source codes but I can't understand it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Answering your question

Since your `addExtra` function doesn't actually do anything with the underlying monad, you can just change the type signature to make it monad-agnostic:

```
addExtra :: Monad m => Int -> State' m Int
addExtra x = get >>= return . (+x)
```

Now you can write this

```
doComplex :: State' IO ()
doComplex = do
    printLog "Starting process..."

    w <- addExtra 5

    printLog $ "Computed value: " ++ show w
```

Which is much prettier, and works just like your old code:

```
*Main> runStateT doComplex 0
Message #1: Starting process...
Message #2: Computed value: 6
((),2)
```

### Aside

I'd probably be tempted to rewrite `addExtra` to one of the following. First, either use do notation

```
addExtra x = do s <- get
                return (s + x)
```

or to use `liftM`, since we're not really using the fact that we have a monad

```
addExtra x = liftM (+x) get
```

or even to use [`gets`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v%3agets) (thanks to Daniel Wagner in the comments)

```
addExtra x = gets (+x)
```

Of course, by this point you probably don't need the additional function. You may as well just write

```
doComplex = do printLog "Starting process..."
               w <- gets (+5)
               printLog $ "Computed value: " ++ show w
```

Similarly, I'd probably rewrite `printLog`. If you ever find yourself `get`ing the state, doing something to it, and `put`ing it back, you probably just want to use `modify`.

```
printLog msg = do modify (+1)
                  n <- get
                  liftIO . putStrLn $ "Message #" ++ show n ++ ": " ++ msg
```

Comment: Yes! Now it seeing so easy ... :) Thank you!

Comment: It's also worth mentioning [`gets`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v:gets), for when you don't necessarily want to save back the new thing (or even the new thing has the wrong type).

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks, I didn't know about `gets`. Will add that in.

Comment: Just a note: `modify` can lead to large thunks, since it doesn't provide a means to force either the old or the new state. In such cases, a `get` followed by a modification and forcing, then a `put` can be necessary. (Someone remind me why there is no `modify'` provided.)

Comment: @Dianiel Fischer, would that be `modify' f = get >>= \s -> let s' = f s in seq s' (put s')`?